# Inequality proof regarding Taylor for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion, contour-integration

I am working on some demanding and revisional exercises to present my work to our Semester Professor and prepare myself for the Semester Exams, this is why I am making such a big post (Any help/tip will be greatly appreciated).

***Exercise :***

Let :

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$

the *Taylor Expansion* of the entire function $f$.

We assume that :

$$|f(z)| \leq Ma^{|z|}, \forall z\in \mathbb C$$

where $a>1$. From the *Cauchy-Taylor Theorem* for any $r>0$, it is :

$$c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

Show that :

***(a)***$$|c_n| \leq M\frac{a^r}{r^n}$$

***(b)***

$$|c_n| \leq M\bigg(\frac{e\ln a}{n}\bigg)^n, n \geq 1$$

$$|c_n| \leq M, n=0$$

***Attempt*** :

***(a)***
We have that : $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n $$

$$|f(z)| \leq Ma^{|z|}, \forall z\in \mathbb C$$

$$|z|=r$$

So, the inequality becomes :

$$|f(z)| \leq Ma^{r}, \forall z\in \mathbb C$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\bigg|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n\bigg| \leq Ma^{r}, \forall z\in \mathbb C$$

Now, I am certainly forgetting something involving *Sums* and the functional $|.|$, because it is obvious that $|z|^n = r^n$ which easily gives the answer. But I cannot understand how the sum gets out of the way, so I would appreciate some thorough help.

***(b)***

For $n=0$, it is obvious that  $|c_n| \leq M$, from the inequality we have proved. Can't get (until this point), how to prove the fact for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: (a) follows from Cauchy's inequality. For (b), try minimising the right hand side of (a) over $r$.

Comment: @copper.hat $|c_n| \leq r^{-n} sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$ Okay got it ! Thanks a lot for the tip, got to say I knew about the inequality but was in the deep back of my brain !